# Keras: ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal (VGGNets)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/7n1SpeudvAE) and I charged a `VGGNet16` pre-trained model using `Keras`

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
  model.add(layer)

model.layers.pop()

for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predict'))
#model.summary()
```

I used `model.save('path/model_1.h5')` to save the model after of training it with `model.fit_generator(...)`

Then I ran out of time in `Colaboratory`. So I wanted to use `model = load_model('path/model_1.h5')` to load again my model instead of loading the model again with `vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()...`

And now I am getting this error:

> ```
> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 4096 and
> 1000. Shapes are [4096,10] and [1000,10]. for 'Assign_61' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [4096,10], [1000,10].
> ```

What am I missing? Than you!

Comment: Thanks to [@deeplizard](https://twitter.com/deeplizard). They helped me to find this answer to my question. I don't know why this didn't appear when I was looking for it. My question is a duplicate of this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482483/valueerror-when-loading-a-previously-saved-retrained-vgg16-model-using-keras)